# How to use python sort json by value for integers

Tags: json, python-2.7, sorting, lambda

I'm trying to sort by descending order by "value"(30, 40, 60).

Here is the sample json

```
{
   "err":0,
   "mes":"xyz",
   "foo":[
      {
         "name":"abc",
         "value":"0",
         "bar":[
            {
               "name":"qwerty",
               "value":"30"
            },
            {"name":"abcd",
               "value":"40" },
            {"name":"xyz",
               "value":"60" }
           ]
   }
   ]
}
```

```
data = req.json()
sorted_data = sorted(data["foo"][0]["bar"], key=lambda i: i["value"], reverse=True)
```

When I sort by "name" it sorts properly in descending order. But when I sort by value, it doesn't sort.

Any Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I sort by "name" it sorts properly in descending order. But when I sort by value, it doesn't sort.

`value` is stored as a string in your data. You need to convert it to a number for sorting properly.

```
sorted(data["foo"][0]["bar"], key=lambda i: int(i["value"]), reverse=True)
```